# How to make a directory on iphone using codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

This sounds like a ridiculous question but I cannot for the life of me make a directory on ios using codenameone. Has anyone done it ? Here is what I try (some dumb tests some not so dumb, im getting desperate here):

```
FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    fs.mkdir("ZZZTESTA");
    fs.mkdir("ZZZTESTB");
    String testpath = fs.getAppHomePath()+"/xxxtesta";
    fs.mkdir(testpath);
     String testpathb = fs.getAppHomePath()+"xxxtestb";
    fs.mkdir(testpathb);
     String testpathC = fs.getAppHomePath()+"xxxtest/";
    fs.mkdir(testpathC);
    String nativetest = fs.toNativePath(testpathb);        
    fs.mkdir(nativetest);        
     String nativetestb = fs.toNativePath(testpathC);        
    fs.mkdir(nativetestb);
```

I have done all kinds of experiments but ALWAYS I get  : Failed to create directory xxxxx.. I will fly to your location and shower you with gifts if you can help :)

Comment: Are you running that code on the simulator or on a real device? Anyway, the following snippet seems to be correct:  FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance(); String testpathb = fs.getAppHomePath()+"xxxtestb";
    fs.mkdir(testpathb);

Answer (score 0):

These would work:

```
String testpathb = fs.getAppHomePath()+"xxxtestb";
fs.mkdir(testpathb);
String testpathC = fs.getAppHomePath()+"xxxtest/";
fs.mkdir(testpathC);
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, but thats exactly my point, they do not work, try it yourself on an iphone :-(

Comment: uh oh, i might be wrong after all this time, somehow Storage IS the same as FileSystemStorage on simulator and Android but not iOS, and somehow ios reports it failed to make the dirs, BUT they are being made... apologies. Im digging deeper now..... man I always get them mixed up.